# Como mostrar o dado repetido somente uma vez?

Tags: mysql

Bem, estou com o seguinte problema no MySQL: Criei duas tabelas uma tabela de livros e outra tabela de autores. Pois bem, eu preciso mostrar o nome do livro com os seus respectivos autores, porém tem alguns livros que possuem mais de 1 autor ou seja usando o seguinte SQL:

```
select l.titulo_livro, a.nome_autor, a.id_autor from tb_livros as l 
join tb_autores as a
where l.id_livro = a.id_livro_escrito;
```

Obtenho o seguinte resultado:

[image: Resultados]

Tem alguma forma de fazer com que não se repita o nome do livro e que os nomes do autores de um mesmo livro se juntem?

Answer (score 7):

Acredito que você esteja procurando pela função [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
select l.id_livro, 
    MIN(l.titulo_livro), 
    GROUP_CONCAT(a.nome_autor),
    GROUP_CONCAT(a.id_autor)
from tb_livros as l join tb_autores as a
    on (l.id_livro = a.id_livro_escrito)
group by l.id_livro
```

Também é possível agrupar por `titulo_livro` se seu modelo garantir que não existam livros com o mesmo título (i.e., `titulo_livro` é uma chave única em `tb_livro`), mas a solução com o identificador é mais robusta.

A função `MIN` não é estritamente necessária no MySQL já que `titulo_livro` é  [funcionalmente dependente](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) de `id_livro`. Dito isso, por questões de compatibilidade com outros bancos optei por não usar diretamente uma coluna que não foi listada na cláusula `group by`. Versões mais recentes do MySQL expõem inclusive uma função [`ANY_VALUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) para lidar com esse típo de situação.

Comment: Nossa cara, muito obrigado.

Comment: Pq foi necessário usar o MIN ?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta para comentar sobre o uso de `MIN`.

Comment: Se a resposta resolveu adequadamente seu problema por favor não se esqueça de aceitá-la.

Comment: Acho que esqueceu! rsrs

Answer (score 0):

Com um distinct ele vai eliminar os resultados iguais:

```
   select distinct l.titulo_livro, a.nome_autor, a.id_autor from tb_livros as l 
join tb_autores as a
where l.id_livro = a.id_livro_escrito;
```

Comment: Um livro pode ter diversos autores. Ele quer que os autores sejam concatenados para cada linha de livro.

Comment: Eu já havia testado com o distinct, mas o resultado continua sendo o mesmo

Comment: o identificador da tabela autores é id_autor ou id_livro_escrito?
Tem como postar a estrutura das tabelas?

Comment: Já deu certo, Obrigado pela ajuda C: